# Return value of cell offset from cell with max value in range

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, max, offset

I am trying to find the function in Google Sheets that returns the value of a cell (name) that is offset from a specific cell that is a MAX in a range.

Here is what I am trying:

```
=OFFSET(CELL("address",INDEX(D13:K13,MATCH(MAX(D13:K13),D13:K13,0))),-11,0)
```

[image: Spreadsheet Example view]

Please help!

Comment: Display image, remove tag from title.

Answer (score 0):

Because Index returns a reference, all you have to do is put the Index result straight into the Offset formula

```
=offset(INDEX(D13:K13,MATCH(MAX(D13:K13),D13:K13,0)),-11,0)
```